# How to add aditional information in plot_tree() function based on node id?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to add a custom label above "value" in a decision tree made with the `DecisionTreeRegressor` class from `sklearn`. Let's suppose the label I want to add is "lambda", and I already have a different value for each terminal node based on their node ID.

My current tree is:
[image]

I'm plotting it with:

```py
from sklearn import tree
tree.plot_tree(model,filled=True, feature_names=["thetas"], node_ids=True, impurity=False)
```

Suppose node #1 should have `lambda=-2` and node #2, `lambda=3`.

How do I add this info?